# json data not received by asp.net mvc action method

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to get some data to a controller from client side script, I am stringfying my data so I receive something like:

```
{"Name":"","Description":"","FieldType":"radio","Fields":[{"Field":{"Name":"something","Value":"nameit"}},{"Field":{"Name":"something else","Value":"dontnameit"}}]}
```

I will need to validate my data on the controller however, in my action I am recieving a null for some reason, if I use object or string? Why is that?

I have had a look into a lot of other posts but it is not clear, do I need to create my own custom IValueProvider implementation? I think there is one available in the ms futures assembley, I tried to locate the file as I do not want all the code inside the dll, but I could not find it...

Any pointers would be appreciated...

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddField(string field) //or object
{
//code here
}
```

Edit: I have followed the post by phill haack but had some errors actually returning the strongly typed object to my view...

my ajax call..

```
{
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        data: jsondata, // { "field" : jsondata},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
...
}
```

I created a custom value provider...

public class Jsonify : ValueProviderFactory
{
        public Jsonify() { }

```
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var jsonData = GetDeserializedJson(controllerContext);
        if (jsonData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //currently used by mvc2 futures
        //return new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(backingStore, 
        //CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        // what do I return?

    }
private static object GetDeserializedJson(ControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // not JSON request
                return null;
            }

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
            string bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
            {
                // no JSON data
                return null;
            }

            //json.net
            var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SurveyField>(bodyText);
            return jsonData;
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult AddSimpleField(SurveyField field) {  ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) which illustrates how you could use a custom `JsonValueProviderFactory` to send a JSON encoded string from client scripts to a controller action and have this action receive it as a strongly typed model and benefit from the validation of the default model binder:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddField(SomeViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the client sent an invalid data
        return Json(new { IsSuccess = false });
    }
    // the model passed validation => do some processing with this model
    return Json(new { IsSuccess = true });
}
```

As Phil Haack explains it this custom `JsonValueProviderFactory` is only necessary if you are working with ASP.NET MVC 2 and is built-in ASP.NET MVC 3 so it should work out of the box.

Comment: I am working with asp.net mvc2 so I will have a look at this now!

Comment: I used this and managed to parse the serialize correctly, however how do I return the actual object to my controller? The standard value provider returns a collection however I could not get this value into my controller? see edit above...